# What is the best way for validate a hidden field in a mvc page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hidden-field, requiredfieldvalidator

How can I enforce Form to validate a hidden field in a MVC page?

it is my View:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.t)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.t)
```

Answer (score 2):

Hidden fields are excluded from validation. On the other hand you could use a normal field that you would simply visually hide in your CSS:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.t, new { @class = "hidden" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.t)
```

and in your CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I have a PartilaView with a hidden field. As you say, I have replaced it by a TextBox like this: `@Html.TextBox(@ViewBag.LookupKey as string,@ViewBag.LookupKey as string,new { @class="hidden" })`. but it doesn't work. in my code, ViewBag.LookupKey is a parameter that I send to my PartialView.